# How can I solve this classical dynamic programming problem?

Tags: dynamic-programming

There are N jewellery shop(s). Each jewellery shop has three kinds of coins - Gold, Platinum, and Diamond having worth value A, B, and C respectively. You decided to go to each of N jewellery shop and take coins from each of the shop. But to do so following conditions must satisfy -

You can take at most 1 coin from an individual shop.
You can take at most X coins of Gold type.
You can take at most Y coins of Platinum type.
You can take at most Z coins of Diamond type.
You want to collect coins from shops in such a way that worth value of coins collected is maximised.

Input Format :

The first line contains an integer N. Where N is the number of jewellery shops.
The second line contains three integers X, Y, Z. Where X, Y, Z denotes the maximum number of coins you can collect of type Gold, Platinum, and diamond respectively.
Then N lines contain three space-separated integers A, B, C. Where A, B, C is the worth value of the Gold, Platinum, and diamond coin respectively.

Output Format :

Print a single integer representing the maximum worth value you can get.

Constraints :

1
<=
N
<=
200

1
<=
X
,
Y
,
Z
<=
N

1
<=
A
,
B
,
C
<
10
9

Example : -

4
2 1 1
5 4 5
4 3 2
10 9 7
8 2 9

Answer:-

27(9+9+5+4)

I tried the obvious greedy approach but it failed :-)

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437293/maximize-consumption-energy

Comment: Tysm :-) How did you find it?!! I got this question from a guy on Codechef. Btw, I would like to say, that you have unknowingly helped me a lot to in being good at dp,memoization, lots of thanks ! God Bless! And you write very good answers on dp always! I think Stack overflow should reward you with prizes!:-)

Comment: Lol. Thanks. I'm still working on the PR question...

Comment: I came to know that it is 100% digit-dp problem, I'll learn that topic :-) Thanks again:p

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*